# 15.04 USB mouse stops working when power source connects or disconnects

Tags: usb, 15.04, mouse

I am facing a strange problem. On 15.04 (64-bit) USB mouse stops working whenever power source connects or disconnects.
However if unplug the mouse and plug it back, it will start working.

Can any one help me fix this issue permanently?
Thanks in advance.